# Posix thread in c

Tags: c, concurrency, posix

I am reading a book called "All of programming" by Andrew and Bracy. Currently, I am on concurrency and came across this function:

```
void smoothParallel(image_t * src, image_t * dst, int nThreads){
   int perThread = src->height/ nThreads + 1;
   int extras = src->height/nThreads;
   ...
   pthread_t * threads = malloc(nThreads * sizeof(*threads));
   for(int i = 0; i < nThreads; i++){
      ...
      perThread--;
   }
   thr_arg * arg = malloc(sizeof(*arg));                     
   arg->src = src;
   arg->dst = dst;
   arg->startY = curr;
   arg->endY = curr + perThread;
   curr += perThread; 
   pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, smoothThread, arg);
   for (int i = 0; i < nThreads ; i++) {
       pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
   }
}
```

So, what I couldn't understand is at `int perThread = src->height/nThreads + 1;` why is it `nThreads + 1` not just `nThreads`, I know its naive thing to ask but I couldn't figure out the reason behind it.

Comment: This specific `perThread` value is used by the actual image processing code, which we cannot see without the book. Presumably if the -1 is removed, there's an off-by-one of one pixel (note that perThread is `(src->height / nThreads) + 1`, not `src -> height / (nThreads + 1)`) Can you include a snippet of the actual code running in the thread?

Comment: I updated the code. There is also a typedef struct_thr_arg with * src, * dst of image_t type and startY,endY of type int. the_arg as struct name,

Comment: Thanks. I'm still not sure exactly what `smoothThread` does internally, so there's not much more insight I can give. My best guess is that this ensures that the amount of work done on each thread is rounded *up* to avoid skipping rows in the image.

Comment: smoothThread, basically smooth an image by iterating through the pixels from startY to endY and another function that calculates weighted pixels which is not given in the book.

Comment: Yep, I think that avoiding skipping rows due to rounding is the best conclusion I can reach.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I found out that nThreads + 1 is the main thread as there are N+1 main thread that spawns thread and wait for worker thread which is just N.